# Sign application package with cerificate profile in tizen studio

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio, tizen-certificate

How to sign application package with certificate profile in Tizen studio?[This](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/managing-projects/certificate-registration) doc only shows how to create Certificate profile but not how to sign the app package.

I want to run the BasicUI app on Tizen emulator and sign the application package is must to run the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sign your application with your own author signing key and a testing distributor signing key in the Tizen Studio. At first create your own Certificate Profile with author and distributor cert. then click right on your project from project explorer and click **Build Signed Package**.

Please check below image:

[image]