# Invalid password when signing Tizen package

Tags: tizen-studio

I'm having trouble signing a basic Tizen package, here are the steps I've followed:

Installation:

- Execute the Tizen studio 3.0 web-ide installer
- Accept the license agreement
- Use the default SDK and Data location (click install)
- Launch the package manager
- Install the 4.0 wearable package
- Exit the package manager and launch Tizen studio

Create the Project:

- Launch with the default workspace
- File->new->Tizen project
- Select template
- Select wearable 4.0
- Select native application
- Select basicUI
- Finish

Create the Certificate:

- Tools->certificate manager
- Click the "+" button to create a new certificate profile
- Name the certificate "TestCert"
- Select "Create a new author certificate" and click next
- Filename:author
- Author Name:Sam
- Password:password
- Select "use the default Tizen distributor certificate" and click Finish
- Exit out of the certificate manager

Try to Build the Package:

- Select the project you created earlier
- Project->build signed package

I get this console output:

```
Initialize... OK
Copying files... OK
Signing... java.io.IOException: Invaild password
```

I am aware of these other stack overflow questions but they do not help me:

[tizen studio (x64) - Build Signed Package - Creating package failed - java.io.IOexception: Invalid password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517875/tizen-studio-x64-build-signed-package-creating-package-failed-java-io-io)

[Sign application package with cerificate profile in tizen studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568674/sign-application-package-with-cerificate-profile-in-tizen-studio)

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

This was all done on Debian 9.

Comment: Tizen Studio can be a difficult beast to tame. Things often fail without giving any meaningful error messages and new versions with bug fixes are few and far between, meanwhile Samsung support never seem to respond to any forum questions. I use TS for working with Samsung Smart TVs and have learned that sometimes the only option left is to install it on a different machine or even different OS version and try again. I can say that I have no problems building using "public" cert profile on Mac

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of what I am saying here.  It appears that Tizen Studio on Linux uses secret-tool (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/secret-tool.1.html) to store certificate passwords.  If the Platform Keyring (Gnome Keyring) is not configured properly, secret-tool fails and Tizen Studio does not appear to propagate this failure properly to the user.  There are too many variables here, but one should first try running the secret-tool that gets shipped with the Tizen Studio IDE (tizen-studio/tools/certificate-encryptor/secret-tool) and see if it throws any errors when trying to save a password.